# How to run certain task with gradle

Tags: gradle

I try to investigate a Gradle and follows some tutorials, but I have confused with the following:

I created are a couple of simple tasks:

```
task startProcess{
    println 'startProcess'
}

task doStep2{
    println 'Step2'
}

task doStep3{
    println 'Step3'
}

task finishProcess{
    println 'finishProcesss'
}
```

And try to execute one of them:

`gradle finishProcess`

Or with `defaultTasks` with command `gradle build`:

```
defaultTasks `finishProcess`

task startProcess{
    println 'startProcess'
}

task doStep2{
    println 'Step2'
}

task doStep3{
    println 'Step3'
}

task finishProcess{
    println 'finishProcesss'
}
```

In both options, I got the same result:

```
> Configure project :
startProcess
Step2
Step3
finishProcesss

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
```

How to execute exactly one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `register`, I think if you did not use it, You're only asking Gradle to execute these tasks.

for example

```
tasks.register('startProcess') {
    doLast {
        println 'startProcess'
    }
}


tasks.register('doStep2') {
    doLast {
        println 'Step2'
    }
}

tasks.register('doStep3') {
    doLast {
        println 'Step3'
    }
}

tasks.register('finishProcess') {
    doLast {
        println 'finishProcesss'
    }
}
tasks.named("build") { finalizedBy("finishProcess") }
```

Registering these tasks, you will be able to call each one indivadually.

If you want to link a specific task, with a `build` task for example.

Then you can use `finalizedBy` like the following.

`tasks.named("build") { finalizedBy("finishProcess") }`

This will call the `finishProcess` task, whenever `build` is triggered.

I strongly recommend the official [gradle documintation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html) for more information about tasks.

Comment: What I understood from your answer - I just should use `doFirst` and `doLast` for correct behavior and that's enough - I put `println` commands in `doFirst` and all works as expected. Thanks